# Why ifTrue and ifFalse are not separated by ; in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

```
a > b
ifTrue:[ 'greater' ]
ifFalse:[ 'less or equal' ]
```

My understanding is that Boolean a > b receives the message  ifTrue:[ 'greater' ], and then ifFalse:[ 'less or equal' ] complying to the generalization:

```
objectInstance selector; selector2
```

But there a semicolon is needed to specify that the receiver of selector2 is not  (objectInstance selector) but objectInstance. Is not the same with the above conditional execution?

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, the ; is for a _cascade_ - a sequence of messages sent to the same object. foo bar; baz. is identical in meaning to foo bar. foo baz.

Comment: your understanding is wrong; its not "receives...AND THEN...", but "receives one message". See my response below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The selector of the method is `Boolean>>ifTrue:ifFalse:`, which means it is *one* method with *two* parameters, not *two* methods with *one* parameter.

Ergo, to invoke the method, you send it the message `ifTrue:ifFalse:` with two block arguments.

Note that for convenience reasons, there are also methods `Boolean>>ifFalse:ifTrue:`, `Boolean>>ifTrue:` and `Boolean>>ifFalse:`.

Answer (score 9):

Everything relevant has already been sayd, but just for your amusement:

As already told,

```
rcvr ifTrue:[...] ifFalse:[...]
```

is the one and single message #'**ifTrue:ifFalse:**' with 2 args sent to *rcvr*. The value of that expression is the one from that message send.
In contrast:

```
rcvr ifTrue:[...]; ifFalse:[...]
```

is a cascade of 2 sequential messages (#'**ifTrue:**' and #'**ifFalse:**'), each with 1 arg sent to *rcvr*. The value of the expression is the one returned from the last send.

Now the funny thing is that booleans do understand **ifTrue:** / **ifFalse:** (each with 1 arg),
so your code works for the side effect (evaluating those blocks), but not for its value.
This means that:

```
a > b ifTrue:[Transcript showCR:'gt'] ; ifFalse:[Transcript showCR:'le']
```

generates the same output as:

```
a > b ifTrue:[Transcript showCR:'gt'] ifFalse:[Transcript showCR:'le']
```

but:

```
msg := a > b ifTrue:['gt'] ; ifFalse:['le']
```

will generate different values in *msg* than:

```
msg := a > b ifTrue:['gt'] ifFalse:['le']
```

depending on the values of *a* and *b*. Try (a b)=(1 2) vs. (a b)=(2 1)...

The problem of many Smalltalk beginners is that they think of **ifXXX:** as syntax, where it is actually a message send which generates value. Also, the semi is not a statement separator as in many previously learned languages, but a sequencing message send construct.

A bad trap for beginners, because the code seems to work for some particular value combinations, whereas it generates funny results for others.
Let's hope your unit tests cover these ;-)

edit: to see where the bad value comes from, take a look at what is returned by the Boolean >> ifFalse: method for a true receiver...